# How to say *develop a long term career*?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I have finished my studies and I want to start my career at a company.

I want to express that I am searching for a position where I can work the next years of my life, so no limited 2 years contract. I want to state that I want to develop a long term career. What are the right words for this?

> After finishing my studies I am now searching for a position as a 
>   xxx within the xx industry where I can develop a long term career and 
>   expand my technical and personal skills.

What are the right words? Can I use *long term career*?

Another idea was *stable*, but I think this does not fit.

> After finishing my studies I am now searching for
>        a position as a xxx within the xx industry where I can 
>       develop a stable career and expand my technical and personal skills.

Comment: *Were* is the past tense of *are*. You need to say *where* here. See the edit. Also avoid using code formatting style for emphasizing. Italicize instead.

Comment: to me your first sentence seems just fine.  good luck!

Comment: if you work in the dotcom industry you should be more honest. "i'm looking for somewhere with the first but not second round in place and plenty of options on the table and you've got to be count driven with no interest in income..."

Answer (score 2):

A *stable career* might be misconstrued as one that doesn't advance. A career is [defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/career?s=t) as something long term, or a life's work. So *long-term* might be unnecessary. You could say something like:

> I have finished my studies and I am now searching for a position as a xxx with the xx industry. I am looking for a company I can commit to and who will commit to me; a company where I can develop my technical and interpersonal skills. I am not looking for a job but for a career.

Comment: Something with the word 'progress' or 'progression' might also work. I believe it's a hit with algorithmic resume-scanners.

Answer (score 0):

> After finishing my studies I am now searching for a position as a xxx within the xx industry where I can develop a long term career and expand my technical and personal skills.

I would make it:

> After graduating from/with.... I am now searching for a position as a XXX within the XXX industry, where I can ideally mature with a like-minded company through expanding my technical and personal skills.

The 'ideally' creates a bit of lee-way, on the off chance the company may be looking for short-term hires or changes its direction in the future. It also makes you seem less picky.

If you want, you can break the sentence down for a little bit of breathing room since it seems a tad bit long, but that is more of a stylistic choice at this stage than a necessity.